# Beginner: Iterative Sequence for Vector Function

Tags: vector, iterators, sequence

I want to create an iterative sequence for two Vectorfunctions, where both are dependent on the same variables and `i` represents the vector.

For simplicity let's assume this Scenario:

```
P=Piecewise[{{G[i],i=1,...,n},{F,{i=n+1}}]
n=10
```

1) Suppose the first step is to evaluate G[1].

2) Dependend on that, the next step has to be the Evaluation of F.

3) Recursivley, G[2] has to be evaluated dependent on the outcome of F.

And so on until n=10 is reached.
My question is, how to implement such an iterative process with which commands to us?

## Edit

I couldn't find a way to create a simple in-/output example to clearify the problem, but maybe words and a simplified description of the model, which I am working on, helps to understand the issue better.

Assumptions:

`n = The number of banks inside a system = 10`

```
P=Piecewise[{{G[i],i=1,...,n},{F,{i=n+1}}]
```

Where `G[i]` is a realized payment vector for a banks obligation and `F` is a function which assesses the quantity of assets in a market. Both depend on a price `p` for this asset and all `Banks[i]`hold this asset.

`G[i]` looks like this:

```
G[i]=Piecewise[{{o[i], if solvent}, {a*o[i], if not solvent}}]
```

Where `o[i]` is the real obligation, which can be paid if `Bank[i]` is solvent
and `a*o[i]` is for simplicity a fraction parameter `a€[0,1]` which the `bank[i]` has to pay if insolvent.

1) Let's assume `Bank[1]` is insolvent and has to sell assets in the market to pay off debts, then the price `p` for the asset will fall according marked to market assumptions.

2) For `Bank[2]` it is now necessary to evaluate how many assets are in the market with the function `F` and how it is standing about its networth, since a devaluation of the asset price in this environment has an negative impact on its networth.

3) Now `Bank[2]`has to calculate its payment vector `G[2]`

4) If `Bank[2]` is still solvent, there will be no more devaluation of the assetprice `p`, but if it is insolvent, the same procedure repeats itself from step one to step 3 for `Bank[3]`.

So the task of these functions is to find an equilibrium price after iteratively calculating the situation for each Bank starting from `Bank[1] to [n]`.

Comment: Could you provide a small but concrete example of input and output?

Comment: I tried to provide a better understanding of the issue. I don't know though if the problem now is clearer. Please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you want `Nest` or `NestList` with or without `Composition`

```
n = 3; (* increase n to 10 for your example *)
```

To display each step

```
clist1 = NestList[{g[#[[2]]], f[g[#[[2]]]]} &, {0, 1}, n] // Flatten[#, 1] & //
   Drop[#, 2] &
```

> {g[1], f[g[1]], g[f[g[1]]], f[g[f[g[1]]]], g[f[g[f[g[1]]]]], f[g[f[g[f[g[1]]]]]]}

For just end result use `Nest` rather than `NestList`

```
c1 = Nest[{g[#[[2]]], f[g[#[[2]]]]} &, {0, 1}, n][[-1]]
```

> f[g[f[g[f[g[1]]]]]]

Alternatively, using `Composition` to take two steps at a time

```
clist2 = NestList[f@*g@# &, 1, n] // Rest
```

> {f[g[1]], f[g[f[g[1]]]], f[g[f[g[f[g[1]]]]]]}

This list is every other term of `clist1`

```
clist2 == Last /@ Partition[{clist1, ""} // Flatten, 2]
```

> True

```
c2 = Nest[f@*g@# &, 1, n]
```

> f[g[f[g[f[g[1]]]]]]

```
c1 == clist1[[-1]] == c2 == clist2[[-1]]
```

> True

Comment: Thank you for the help, i think these functional programming commands lead into the right direction and might be the solution for the problem. I try to play a little with them and see if it works.

Comment: And I also made a mistake by describing F as a Function for Vector [i]. However F is not a function for a specific Vector [i], but general function, which will give out a clear value, and not a Vector. I corrected that mistake in the Edit Part. However this just makes it simpler and the Nest argument still might be the solution